# The type or namespace name 'Core' does not exist in the namespace 'AuntieDot'

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

I have 4 PCL's, and they are all targeted at the same Frameworks:

AuntieDot:

[image: AuntieDot]

AuntieDot.Authentication:

[image: AuntieDot.Authentication]

AuntieDot.Core:

[image: AuntieDot.Core]

AuntieDot.Models:

[image: AuntieDot.Models]

But for some reason, the usage of 'AuntieDot.Core.Helpers' in the 'AuntieDot.Authentication' namespace (despite 'AuntieDot.Core' being added as a reference into 'AuntieDot.Authentication', it's saying it doesn't exist. I've googled around and the only replies I've gotten is that I need to make sure the other libraries are targeted at the same frameworks, which they are.

The only external code I'm using is JSON.net, which I added via NuGet so I don't think that is the issue.

The code in the 'AuntieDot.Core';
[image: Helpers]
[image: Exceptions]

The code that is throwing the issue is only complaining in the error list and on compile, it doesn't have a Red-Underline, like usual:

[image: Error :(]

I just thought that maybe posting the Build Output might help;
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=wn74UKyc

Comment: You haven't told us anything about what types are in those assemblies. References and namespaces are entirely different - unless `AuntieDot.Core` contains public types in the `AuntieDot.Core.Helpers` namespace, that assembly is irrelevant.

Comment: Added, sorry for overlooking that.

Comment: What happens if you explicitly specify a type (without the `using` directive), e.g. `AuntieDot.Core.Helpers.VariousFunctions.SendGetRequestAsync(null, null)`?

Comment: I get the same error, but it talks about the line with the call on it. (http://i.imgur.com/vu1raV8.png)

Comment: Added a the Build Output, it might help.

Comment: Hmm. That is odd. Is the solution somewhere available for us to look at it?

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/rBMJzQiR

Comment: Sorry, I meant the whole solution (code and all). But it looks like you're sorted now.

Comment: Oh, I just assumed you were wondering why the fix I posted worked and wanted to have a look at the csproj to see why. Apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the Issue, it seems there is a bug with VS when targeting the frameworks I'm targeting. I found this by googleing the `The currently targeted framework ".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78" does not include "System.Net.Requests, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral` error in the Build Output, this brought me to someone having the same issue on Microsoft's [Connect Site](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/770242/build-error-with-dependent-portable-class-libraries-that-target-windows-phone-8). Seems they are fixing this bug soon, but until then Microsoft released this Workaround, thanks to Dave on the VS Team,

> Thanks once again for the bug report. We've found another workaround
>   that does not require you to change the frameworks you are targeting.
>   To workaround this, edit the project in a text editor, and add the
>   following underneath the last "Import" element:

```
<Target Name="_SetFullFrameworkFolderToProfile"
 AfterTargets="GetReferenceAssemblyPaths">

<PropertyGroup>
 <_FullFrameworkReferenceAssemblyPaths>$(TargetFrameworkDirectory)</_FullFrameworkReferenceAssemblyPaths>
</PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

Andddd boom:

[image: swag]

Comment: That really helped. Note that we need to add the target to the project where the error occurs and not to the PCL project that is referenced. The solution is same if your error shows System.Net.Primitives instead of System.Net.Request.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before when referencing other projects in the same solution.  My problem was simply that I had that ONE project set to build as `Release` while the rest of the solution was set as `Debug`.  This meant that even though I referenced the project correctly, the compiler wasnt finding the compiled DLL in the debug directory.  Any chance that is it?

Comment: They are all set to Debug, sadly.

Comment: Very strange.  I just had the same issue, but the build type was all it was.  Take a look at the project reference.  Does it show a "Path" and "Runtime Version" for the `Core` dll just like the other dll's?  If not then the compiler simply cant find the dll it needs at compile time.

Comment: The Path looks good, but the Runtime version looks wrong. How did you fix that? (http://i.imgur.com/TeqQPAk.png)